# INGRESAR AdSense en el <Head>

Tags: html, html5

¿Cómo puedo ingresar un Adsense dentro de un Head? Ya tengo la estructura y el código que voy a colocar, ¿cómo lo puedo implementar?

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-3875903759149355",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu sitio muestra muchos HTMLs. Estos pueden tener archivos .html, o bien estar generados por .php o .asp, etc.

Cada archivo HTML (generado o no), tendrá esta estructura:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Deberás buscar  y pegar el código de AdSense dentro de ese bloque. Si hay más de un archivo, tendrás que hacerlo en todos los que sean relevantes.